# Link to document not working

Tags: document-library, hyperlink

I have a some script in which I am using some dropdowns on my main page which a bunch of links in them.  I have one in particular that is linked to a document within a document library.  I am able to see the document correctly when I click the link but others are getting "page does not exist".

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: Did you check if it was a permission issue? Can they see the document directly in the library?

Comment: Could also be a publishing issue. Is versioning available on the library? Make sure a major version is published, and also make sure it is checked in

Comment: @DamjanTomic are you referring to individual document permissions?

Comment: @kevins versioning is not turned on.

Comment: @FlatBanana: Yes, that's what I refer to. Can the user who gets the "page does not exist" error view/open that document directly from the library?

Comment: @DamjanTomic I will need to look at that.  Would it matter though as every employee has the baseline of “read”?

Comment: "Read" should definitely be enough. You should also check if the "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" option is turned on in "Versioning settings" (the same page where you checked the setting @kevins mentioned).

Comment: I have verified versioning and it was never activated.  It just seems as if I am the only one able to view the document through the shortcut.